# How does google android repo file work?

Tags: python, bash

Quote of [the script](https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo):

```
!/bin/sh                                                                       

## repo default configuration
##
REPO_URL='https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo'
REPO_REV='stable'
...
magic='--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--'
"""exec" python -E "$0" "$@" """#$magic"
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  if sys.argv[-1] == '#%s' % magic:
    del sys.argv[-1]
del magic   
..all python from here on..
```

How can they put bash and python in a single script and make it run?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I understand it:
The script is first invoked as a shell script and then calls python on line 23, so if you invoked the `sync` command on repo it would do the following:

```
"""exec" python -E "$0" "$@" """#$magic"
```

which *I believe* turns into:
    exec "python -E "repo" "sync" "#--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--"
This then calls the script `repo` as a python script.  You will notice that all of the syntax is legal in bash and python down to the `exec` line.  The triple quotes on line 23 are really sweet, they work in the shell script and then work as a doc string in python.  How awesome is that!

In python `"""` begin and end a docstring which can span multiple lines.  Very roughly, it's a very special kind of comment that the python help system can read.  In bash, *I believe* that the double quote is matched to the next double quote the interpreter encounters. So the first two quotes, quote the null string and it disappears from the interpreter.  In our example, the next quotes quote the `exec` keyword.  The last set of triple quotes, `"""#$magic"`, first quote the null string and then quote the `#$magic` argument.  Since double quotes allow the variable `$magic` to be expanded, it becomes, `#--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--` and passed as an argument.

If you look at the script with a text editor with syntax highlighting as a shell script and then as a python script, it's even easier to see.  This is an extremely clever, way of starting the shell script and then giving control to python.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you elaborate more about how the triple quotes work in both bash and python?

Comment: """ begins a multi-line quote in Python, which extends to the next occurrence of """. In Bash it's just an empty pair of double quotes (a double-quoted empty string) adjacent to another double-quoted string which extends up to the next double quote. Now, in Python, strings are just ignored constants, but in Bash you can double-quote a command; so """exec" evaluates to the `exec` command after quote removal.